# Can I create nodes and relationship between them in single query?

Tags: memgraphdb

I know that that I can create a relationship between exiting nodes. But can I create nodes and relationship at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by single query you mean in a single run, yes, it can be done. You can use the CREATE clause for creating two new nodes and a directed relationship between them:

```
CREATE (c1:City {name: "UK"}),
       (c2:City {name: "London", population_size: 9000000})
       (c1)<-[r:IN]-(c2)
RETURN c1, c2, r;
```

Comment: "If by single query you mean in a single run"...? Why do you need to ask clarification on a question you yourself asked within a minute of providing the answer...?

Comment: Hi! I'm embarking on new area of IT and I'm learning Cypher. By reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/answer-your-own-question-qa-style and https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer I got the impression that I'm allowed to do this. I'm on winter break from my classes and I've decided to transform all of my notes from previous semester to Stackoverflow so that future generations will be able to find all of the answers that I was struggling with.

Comment: No, that's fine, you can absolutely answer your own question. I was just curious how you could misunderstand yourself that you had to make sure what your question meant in your answer, even using "you" as if it wasn't written by the same person.

Comment: I was told at one of my classes that passive voice should be avoided as much as possible in instructions. So I'm writing if I was to two persons.